# mysqli: Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quero guardar o resultado de uma query em `$_SESSION`, porém quando tento recuperar a query da `$_SESSION`, acontece o errro

> "Couldn't fetch mysqli_result".

Obs.: utilizo o `session_start()`. Segue o código:

Query mysql:

```
$user_types = $mysqli->query("SELECT tipo from tipo_usuario WHERE usuario = '$user_id' ORDER BY tipo");
```

Colocando o resultado na $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['user_types'] = $user_types;
```

Quando tento recuperar a query pela `$_SESSION`, aqui que acontece o erro:

```
while($row = $_SESSION['user_types']->fetch_array())
```

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor guardar o valor especifico, do que o resource (retorno de `query()`). Basicamente o que você deve guarda é o retorno de `fetch_array()`

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando por um ponteiro para um recurso aberto, e não um resultado. Isso não funciona. Ou você pega os dados e guarda num array, ou melhor ainda, abre a conexão e faz a query onde for usar.

Se REALMENTE precisar da query em página separada, faça assim:

<sub>Pagina A</sub>

```
$_SESSION['sql'] = "SELECT tipo from tipo_usuario WHERE usuario = '$user_id' ORDER BY tipo";
```

<sub>Pagina B</sub>

```
// abra a conexao nessa pagina aqui 
$user_types = $mysqli->query($_SESSION['sql']);

while($user_types->fetch_array()) {
    ...
```